# Time complexity of the code segment

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the time complexity of the following code snippet

```
sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    if(i % j == 0) {
      for(k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
        sum = sum + k;          
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

What i think , that out of N iterations of First loop, only 1 value which is 0 allowed to enter K loop and from i = 1.....N, K loop never runs.

So, only 1 value of I runs j loop N times and k loop N times and for other values of I only J loop runs N times

So, is the TC = O(N^2) ?

Comment: Does this help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279362/show-that-the-solution-to-tn-tn-1-n-is-on2

Comment: how it follows t(n) = t(n-1) + n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here let **d(n)** is the number of divisors of n.

I see your program doing **O(n)** work(innermost loop) for **O( d(n) )** number of divisors of each i (i looping from 0 to n in outermost loop: **O(n)** ).

Its complexity is **O( n * d(n) * n )**.

[Reference](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/)

for large n, *d() ~ O( exp( log(n)/log(log n) ) )*.

So the overall complexity is **O( n^(2 + 1/log(log n) ) )**.

Comment: Can u elaborate more ?

Comment: @stackuser, elaborated.

Comment: Does this method takes into account that K runs N times, only for I=0, and otherwise, it is not even running.

Comment: @stackuser The `k` loop runs any time `j` divides evenly into `i`. For example, if `i` is 6, then the `k` loop runs 4 times, since 1,2,3 and 6 all divide evenly into 6. Put a `printf` after the `if(i%j==0)` to see that.

Comment: thanks @user3386109. stackuser, please do ask if you still have doubt.

Comment: @dd2 According to your formula the complexity goes to n^2 with n being large enough.

Comment: @stackuser Please, check out my answer, I think it is closer to being a correct one.

Comment: @0kcats, then what is the problem in my answer.

Comment: @dd2 Actually, it seems your formula does not go to n^2, because it seems that n^(1 / log log n) is a growing function. Also, it seems n^(1/log log n) grows faster than log n, so you probably gave little-o estimate.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another answer. Lets replace the inner loop with an abstract func():

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
    if(i%j==0) {
      func();        
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly, forgetting the calls to func(), the complexity M to calculate all (i % j) is O(n^2).

Now, we can ask ourselves how many times the func() is called. It's called once for each divisor of i. That is it is called d(i) times for each i. This is a [Divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) D(n). D(n) ~ n log n for large n.
So func() is called n log n times. At the same time the func() itself has complexity of O(n). So it gives the complexity P = O(n * n log n).

So total complexity is M + P = O(n^2) + O(n^2 log n) = O(n^2 log n)

**Edit**
Vow, thanks for downvote! I guess I need to prove it using python.
This code prints out n, how many times the inner loop is called for n, and outputs ratio of the latter and Divisor summatory function

```
import math

n = 100000
i = 0
z = 0
gg = 2 * 0.5772156649 - 1
while i < n:
  j = 1
  while j <= i:
    if i % j == 0:
      #ignoring the most inner loop just calculate the number of times it is called
      z+=1

    j+=1

  if i > 0 and i % 1000 == 0:
    #Exact divisor summatory function, to make z/Di converge to 1.0 quicker
    Di = (i * math.log(i) + i * gg)
    #prints n Di z/Di
    print str(i) + ": " + str(z) + ": " + str(z/Di)

  i+=1
```

Output sample:

```
24000: 245792: 1.00010672544
25000: 257036: 1.00003672445
26000: 268353: 1.00009554815
```

So the most inner loop is called n * log n times, and total complexity is n^2 * log n